# Is LMM (lme4) the right way to go?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, p-value, random-effects-model, post-hoc

I do realize that there are already some questions about the p-values in lme4 and the nested effects but I've got a somehow specific case and failed to find anything that applies to this.

I have collected ratings of **accent from 80 participants**. The ratings are on a **1-9 scale**, which was proved to work like a linear scale with almost 1.0 correlation (I also have comprehensibility scores and intelligibility ratio but the procedure should be the same). So my **dependent variable** here is **accent rating (1-9)**

I have divided the participants randomly into **5 different groups** (**between subject design**) and they all rated **100 utterances** in **2 conditions** (**within subject design**):

***(1) baseline*** (same across the groups, 40 utterances to control for possible differences between the groups) and

***(2) experimental*** (60 utterances, this part was different for each group, **each group was listening to the same audio but with different visuals, one group had audio only for control.**

I am interested primarily in the relationship between the **accent score** and type of **visual** (or its lack).

Additionally there are some other variables that I would prefer to model as fixed effects (to see their influence on the ratings in the *experimental* - with visuals - condition). The most important is the **sex** of the speaker.

Since the audios are not exactly the same length (but close) and obviously have easier and more difficult words I  was thinking of putting the audio -> **item** as a random effect along with the **subject**.

If I understand everything correctly, the **subject** in my research should be **nested** in the "group" variable (each subject belongs to only one group and they do both baseline and experimental conditions within that group). **Audio** (=item), should, however, be **crossed**, because the same audio appears in the baseline for all the groups and the same audio (but different from baseline) appears in the experimental condition for all groups (the only difference is the presence of absence of the visual and the type of visual).

So, what I was trying right now is:

```
model = lmer(accent ~ group * condition * sex + (1|subject) + (1|item) + (1|voice), data=data)
```

**Here:**

`group` - 5 levels (as a column with group names), each subject is ONLY in one group

`condition` - 2 levels (as a column with "baseline" or "experimental" tags), each participant completed BOTH baseline and experimental conditions within their own group.

`sex` - gender of the speaker (not the listener), there are the same speakers in each group - same audio.

`subject` - participant, 100 responses per participant recorded, each subject is only in one group but goes through both *baseline* and *experimental* conditions

`item` - audio number as a factor not int (1-100),the audios are in all groups the same (it is here to control for the differences in audios - like length or difficulty of the vocabulary)

`voice` - one of the 10 speakers recorded

So here are **my questions**:

(1) I don't really have anyone to ask at my university so I have to ask here. I am wondering if my approach (and modeling) is correct? Any reasons why I should NOT use lme (and use mixed effects ANOVA instead, for example?)

(2) Also after getting the model I need to get the p-value (for all comparison here) and I'm not sure what is the best way to do that so I would appreciate any help. What is the best practice? (I'm checking lmerTest now)

(3) There is one other thing that keeps bugging me. Half of the participants in each group got the baseline -> experimental order while the other half got experimental -> baseline order for the balance. However, this order might have had affected half of the ratings and I am wondering if there is any way to put it into the model.

(4) I need to make sure that there was NO difference between the groups in the baseline and I am not sure where to look for that.

(5) Any good way to check for influential data points?

(6) Is this even the right way to go, since I am getting strips (patterns) in the plot after fitting the model? If not, what would be? Mixed design ANOVA?

Here is the actual data frame:

```
'data.frame':   8000 obs. of  19 variables:
$ group                : Factor w/ 5 levels "asiapic","asiavid",..: 3 3 3 3 3...
$ subject              : Factor w/ 80 levels "P17001","P17002",..: 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ gender_part          : Factor w/ 2 levels "female","male": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ order                : Factor w/ 2 levels "first","second": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ condition            : Factor w/ 2 levels "baseline","experiment": 1 1 1 ...
$ voice                 : Factor w/ 10 levels "adam","aline",..: 6 7 6 9 3 ...
$ sex                  : Factor w/ 2 levels "f","m": 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ accent               : int  3 7 4 9 4 3 4 7 8 4 ...
$ ratio                : num  0.571 0.857 0.75 0.714 0.429 ...
$ item                 : Factor w/ 100 levels "90","26","50",..: 1 2 3 4 5...
$ comprehensibility    : int  7 3 7 3 8 5 6 5 3 7 ...
```

I realize that these are very basic questions but I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I edited the question to be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you only have 5 groups, I wouldn’t use a nested random effect for groups, just the random effect per subject and per item.

Regarding testing, you can have a look at the [**lmerTest**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=lmerTest) package.

Comment: Thank you so much, so that would be (1|subject) and (1|item), right?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant.